# Recursion for dynamic menu in ASP.NET Core MVC using partial View

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to display dynamic menu with partial view using recursion. But I didn't found any solution for that. I had this code.

Controller

```cs
public IActionResult GetMenu()
{
    var catAll = _categoryservice.GetCategories();

    var model = catAll.Where(category => category.ParentCategoryId == null).Select(x => new ViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        ParentCategoryId = x.ParentCategoryId,        
    }).ToList();
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Partial/_GetMenu.cshtml", model);
}
```

I want to call Controller ActionMethod in Layout Page for dynamic menu. I used RenderAction but that's not working.

_GetMenu.cshtml(partial view)

```
@{ Func<dynamic, IHtmlContent> 
 ShowMenu(IEnumerable<SarvamCart.Domain.Models.ViewModel> cats) =>
    @<ul>
        @foreach (var cat in cats)
        {
            <li>
                @cat.Name
                @if (cat.Child != null && cat.Child.Any())
                {
                    @ShowMenu(cat.Child)
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>;
}
```

I passed this Recursion code in partial but this is also not working.

It gives me proper result but I want my layout of dynamic menu like this:

[image]

Please help me with this

Comment: Pretty sure that should be `Func<IEnumerable<SarvamCart.Domain.Models.ViewModel>, IHtmlContent> ShowMenu = @<ul> @foreach (var cat in item) .... </ul>;`

Comment: And remember to call it once at the end `@ShowMenu(Model)`.

Comment: No, This is also not working.The model get null values

Comment: How to use the renderAction and recursion in .net core mvc for dynamic menu?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ajax to call controller action.Here is a demo:
Layout.cshtml:

```
...
 <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <div id="menu">

            </div>
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
...
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Test1/GetMenu",
        }).done(function (data) {
            $("#menu").html(data);
        });
    })
</script>
```

Test1/GetMenu:

```
public IActionResult GetMenu()
    {
        var catAll = _categoryservice.GetCategories();

        var model = catAll.Where(category => category.ParentCategoryId == null).Select(x => new ViewModel
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            ParentCategoryId = x.ParentCategoryId,
            Child=x.Child

        }).ToList();
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Partial/_GetMenu.cshtml", model);
    }
```

database data:

[image]

Sample `model` data:
[image]
ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ParentCategoryId")]
        public List<ViewModel> Child { get; set; }

        
    }
```

_GetMenu.cshtml(partial view):

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html
@using xxx.Models
@model IEnumerable<ViewModel>
@ShowMenu(Model.ToList(), new ViewModel())(null)
@{
    Func<dynamic, IHtmlContent> ShowMenu(List<ViewModel> cats, ViewModel parent) =>
    @<ul>
        @foreach (var cat in cats)
        {
            <li>
                @cat.Name
                @if (cat.Child.Count() > 0)
                {
                    @ShowMenu(cat.Child, cat)(null)
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>;
}
```

result:
[image]